# How to change only the style of the given font?

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I have a font variable
  `static public Font bold_13 = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 13);` which is set to text. Now based on some condition I need to change the style of the font.

One possible solution which i found was

```
field.setFont(field.getFont().deriveFont(Font.ITALIC));
```

I cant use the same in my application because I dont know the field when i am changing the style. So I cant use like `field.setFont`!

Comment: For all fields? Or do you rather wish to retrieve which field is concerned. From most listeners, the `event.getSource()` will provide that info.

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I already saw the solution which you have pointed out but I can not use the same in my application.

Comment: *"..I dont know the field.."*  Why not?  For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).